# Join two same columns from two dataframes, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for fastest way to join columns with same names using separator.
my dataframes:

```
df1:
A,B,C,D
my,he,she,it

df2:
A,B,C,D
dog,cat,elephant,fish
```

expected output:

```
df:
A,B,C,D
my:dog,he:cat,she:elephant,it:fish
```

As you can see, I want to merge columns with same names, two cells in one.
I can use this code for `A` column:

```
df=df1.merge(df2)
df['A'] = df[['A_x','A_y']].apply(lambda x: ':'.join(x), axis = 1)
```

In my real dataset i have above 30 columns, and i dont want to write same lines for each of them, is there any faster way to receive my expected output?

Comment: what are you merging on? index?

Comment: In your case there's columns that the name doesn't match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `concat` and `groupby` ?

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0)
df3 = df3.groupby(df3.index).transform(lambda x : ':'.join(x)).drop_duplicates()
print(df3)
         A       B             C        D
0  my:dog  he:cat  she:elephant  it:fish
```

Comment: are you shure that you want to use concat without `axis=1` ? i will check it

Comment: no using `axis=0` gives us the flexibility of grouping along the index and concating the rows into your joined values but it's hard to say without all your business requirements.

Comment: this is good answer for my dataset in question, but i have one question about my real dataset, using your code i am receiving as answer, headers of , my dataset, any idea? like: A:B B:C :C:D:A. i think is because of index, so this solution is only for ideal dataset

Comment: did you use `apply` or `transform` ?

Comment: try it with `.transform(lambda x : ':'.join(x)).drop_duplicates()` as above

Comment: but this method is using index, so if my simillar rows have different indexes, it wont work right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202213/discussion-between-datanovice-and-sygneto).

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
df3 = df1 + ':' + df2
print(df3)
       A       B         C             D 
0   my:dog  he:cat  she:elephant    it:fish
```

This is good because if there's columns that doesn't match, you get `NaN`, so you can filter then later if you want:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['my'], 'B': ['he'], 'C': ['she'], 'D': ['it'], 'E': ['another'], 'F': ['and another']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['dog'], 'B': ['cat'], 'C': ['elephant'], 'D': ['fish']})
df1 + ':' + df2
       A       B          C             D    E   F
0   my:dog  he:cat  she:elephant    it:fish NaN NaN
```

Comment: I would avoid loops in dataframes

Comment: I found out another solution :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by simply adding the two dataframe with a separator.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"], index=[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"], index=[0])

df1["A"] = "my"
df1["B"] = "he"
df1["C"] = "she"
df1["D"] = "it"
df2["A"] = "dog"
df2["B"] = "cat"
df2["C"] = "elephant"
df2["D"] = "fish"

print(df1)
print(df2)

df3 = df1 + ':' + df2
print(df3)
```

This will give you a result like:

```
A   B    C   D
0  my  he  she  it
     A    B         C     D
0  dog  cat  elephant  fish
        A       B             C        D
0  my:dog  he:cat  she:elephant  it:fish
```

Is this what you try to achieve? Although, this only works if you have same columns in both the dataframes. The extra columns will have nans. What do you want to do with the columns those are not same in df1 and df2? Please comment below to help me understand your problem better.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do:

```
df = df1 + ':' + df2
print(df)
```

Which is simple and effective

This should be your answer